# Azure Search with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, azure, elasticsearch, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

I am new to Azure Cognitive Search and was able to get Azure Search work with SQL Server but I want to use Azure Search for PostgreSQL. I could not find it in the documents that Azure Search supports PostgreSQL. Can someone confirm that for me?

I created an Instance of Azure Cognitive Search and click on Import Data and on Connect Data for the data source, I only see Cosmos, Azure SQL, SQL Server on VMs, Table Storage and there is no Postgres.

If I am missing something, can you please provide an official documentation or an example of how can I use PostgreSQL with Azure Search?

Comment: Azure Cognitive Search supports any data source since it has an API that allows you to push data to the search index. Any data you can access with code can be pushed via the API. I would argue that pushing the data via the API is always the preferred choice since it allows you to programmatically modify your data for search-specific purposes before submitting it to the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Import Data, Postgres is not a supported data source and you can confirm in the official doc:

```
type    Required. Must be one of the supported data source types:

azuresql for Azure SQL Database
cosmosdb for the Azure Cosmos DB SQL API
azureblob for Azure Blob Storage
adlsgen2 for Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
azuretable for Azure Table Storage
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source#request-body

However, you can program the data extraction and push data to your index. In fact, I often prefer this way.

If you don't have the index created, you can do it using the following REST api definition:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index

Then, you add data using the following REST api:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [Azure Data Factory pipeline that supports PostgreSQL as source](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-postgresql?tabs=data-factory) and use a staged storage account, then you can create a [Blob indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage) or use an [Azure Cognitive Search index sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-search?tabs=data-factory).

In this [temporary documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-how-to-index-power-query-data-sources#migrate-a-postgresql-data-pipeline) you can find how to set the Azure Data Factory pipeline for this integration.